# Filtering query in django with multiple params

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Is it someway to filter querysets with multiple optional parameters in Django more efficiently?

For ex. I have product list and user can filter it by using multiple GET params. 6 params in this case. Thanks.

```
class ProductList(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.order_by('-created_at')
        category_id = self.request.GET.get('category_id')
        color = self.request.GET.get('color')
        size = self.request.GET.get('size')
        status = self.request.GET.get('status')
        date_from = self.request.GET.get('date_from')
        date_to = self.request.GET.get('date_to')
        if category_id:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category_id=category_id)
        if color:
            queryset = queryset.filter(color=color)
        if size:
            queryset = queryset.filter(size=size)
        if status:
            queryset = queryset.filter(status=sistatusze)
        if date_from:
            queryset = queryset.filter(created_at__gte=date_from)
        if date_to:
            queryset = queryset.filter(created_at__lte=date_to)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a utility function that will not filter the conditions where the value is `None`:

```
def filter_if_not_none(qs, **kwargs):
    return qs.filter(**{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None})
```

then we can use this utility as:

```
class ProductList(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = ProblemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.order_by('-created_at')
        return filter_qs_if_not_none(
            queryset,
            category_id=self.request.GET.get('category_id')
            color=self.request.GET.get('color')
            size=self.request.GET.get('size')
            status=self.request.GET.get('status')
            created_at__gte=self.request.GET.get('date_from')
            created_at__lte=self.request.GET.get('date_to')
        )
```